# Importing URL Rewrites Directly to Database is successful but not showing in admin nor working on the frontend

Tags: url-rewrite, database-update, ee-1.14.2.0

I have a CSV file that I am using to import about 600 entries to the core_url_rewrite table of my database.

The data that I am submitting is formatted as follows:

```
 url_rewrite_id     store_id    id_path                 request_path    target_path     is_system   options     description         category_id product_id
                    1           custom_168920477350     about-site      about-us/                   RP          Old URLs
```

Everything imports fine and all of the data is in the appropriate columns but when I go to the Magento backend to look at the URLs they are not displayed even after I reindex and clear cache.

Also, of course, they do not redirect on the front end.

**Edit**: I see now that Enterprise uses a different table. I'm investigating these to see if the import will work the same way. In the meantime I'm interested in any and all feedback.